# Scala - How to get constructore fields values in reflection?

Tags: scala, reflection

I'm pretty new to scala and struggling a bit with reflection.

Given the below class:

```
class Person (name: String) {
 .....
}
```

and the given instance:

```
val p = new Person ("MyName")
```

How can i retrieve the value "MyName" in reflection?

BTW - I tried with java reflection using getClass.getDeclaredFields(), but without luck...

Thanks!

Comment: http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/overview.html

Answer (score 3):

`name` is not a member of the class in your example, it's just a function parameter of the constructor. The difference in scala in rather subtle, because the whole class is defined inside the constructor body, so, it is, effectively, a closure, and you can use the parameters everywhere, but still, there is a difference.

`class Person(val name: String)` or `class Person(var name: String`) declares a class with an instance member (either final or writable) `name`.
`class Person(name: String)` has no instance variables, `name` is just a parameter to the constructor.

Case classes are special, as they treat all constructor parameters as vals by default, this is "syntactic sugar": `case class Person(name: String)` really means `case class Person(val name: String).

Answer (score -1):

I think you should add modifier var or val when defining constructor.
i.e,

class Person (var name: String) {
 .....
}

and to retrieve value "MyName", you can do,

val p= new Person("MyName");

and Name is: p.name